# Spring: moving the stradegy to code or keep in the xml file?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I have an interface for language translation as defined below.

```
public interface TranslationService {
  public TranslationResult translate(TranslationRequeset req);
  public int maxTranslatableCount();
}
```

And there are several implementations of the interface by using Google,Bing...etc as follows:

```
public class BingTranslationServiceImpl implements TranslationService {
 public TranslationResult translate(TranslationRequeset req){}
 public int maxTranslatableCount(){return 10000;}
}


public class GoogleTranslationServiceImpl implements TranslationService {
  public TranslationResult translate(TranslationRequeset req){}
  public int maxTranslatableCount(){return 2000;}
}

public class FooTranslationServiceImpl implements TranslationService {
  public TranslationResult translate(TranslationRequeset req){}
  public int maxTranslatableCount(){return 50000;}
}
```

Then in our client code, we had to perform fail-over if a particular translation service fails.

In order to achieve that, I introduced a "TranslationProxy" defining the fail-over strategy in a List as follows:

Basically this iterate through the list if a particular service failed to translate.

```
public class TranslationProxy implements TranslationService {
   private List<TranslationService> services;

   TranslationResult translate(TranslationRequeset req) {
        //
   }
    public List<TranslationBusinessLogic> getServices() {
        return services;
    }
    public void setServices(List<TranslationBusinessLogic> services) {
        this.services = services;
    }

}
```

Then in my Spring configuration I defined the service implementations as follows :

```
    <bean id="bing" class="com.mycompany.prj.BingTranslationServiceImpl" scope="singleton"/> 
<bean id="google" class="com.mycompany.prj.GoogleTranslationServiceImpl" scope="singleton"/> 
<bean id="foo" class="com.mycompany.prj.FooTranslationServiceImpl" scope="singleton"/>
```

And for each fail-over strategy I define "TranslationProxy" beans as follows :

```
   <bean id="translationProxy_Bing_Google" class="com.mycompany.prj.TranslationProxy" scope="singleton">
        <property name="services">
            <list>
                <ref bean="bing"/>
                <ref bean="google"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="translationProxy_Foo_Bing_Google" class="com.mycompany.prj.TranslationProxy" scope="singleton">
        <property name="services">
            <list>
                <ref bean="foo"/>
                <ref bean="bing"/>
            <ref bean="google"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

In the client code :

```
class SomeBusinessLogic {
  @Autowired
  @Qualified("translationProxy_Bing_Google")
  private TranslationService translationService;

  public void some_method_which_uses_translation() {
    result = translationService(request);
  }

}
```

another place :

```
class SomeAnotherBusinessLogic {
  @Autowired
  @Qualified("translationProxy_Foo_Bing_Google")
  private TranslationService translationService;

  public void some_method_which_uses_translation_with_different_failover_stradegy() {
    result = translationService(request);
  }

}
```

**Isn't this the most clean way to implement this failover-stradegy ?**

I was asked to move the the failover-stradegy in to the client code.

Something like following (which is impossible in spring):

```
class SomeBusinessLogic {
  @Autowired
  @SomeAnnotationDefiningTheStradegy("bing","google")
  private TranslationService translationService;

  public void some_method_which_uses_translation() {
    result = translationService(request);
  }
```

Here the "SomeAnnotationDefiningTheStradegy" is an annotation which will fill the List with the beans defined in the arguments.

Answer (score 2):

First, I recommend you to make an enum containing all translation services (`enum TranslationServiceProvider {BING, GOOGLE, FOO}`) and use it instead of Strings. Adding a method to `TranslationService` interface returning provider (`TranslationServiceProvider getProvider()`) can be useful too.

In my opinion, the most straightforward option is would be something like:

```
class SomeAnotherBusinessLogic {

    private TranslationService translationService;

    @Autowired
    public void setTranslationService(TranslationDecider translationDecider) {
        translationService = translationDecider.getProxyFor(
            TranslationServiceProvider.BING, TranslationServiceProvider.FOO);
    }

    ...
}

@Component
public class TranslationDeciderImpl implements TranslationDecider {

    @Autowired
    private List<TranslationService> translationServices;

    public TranslationProxy getProxyFor(TranslationServiceProvider ... providers) {
        List<TranslationService> services = // translationServices filtered using getProvider()
        return new TranslationProxy(services);
    }

}
```

`TranslationProxy`is not managed by Spring, but probably is not necessary. If it is, a `TranslationProxyFactory` will be required.

Comment: +1 Another good option. Again, all of the above are nearly identical in execution. It just depends on how the OP wants to structure it.

Comment: Creating an enum for the different (simple) translation services leads to code changes when a fourth simple translation service is added. The question was to enfore a code change for the failover strategy, not the individual translation services.

Answer (score 1):

Functionally, I see no difference between your two options. You are clearly using, essentially, a `ServiceCoordinator` which you call a `TranslationProxy` to handle your list of `TranslationService` implementations, ultimately making use of the [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). It does look a little tedious to define multiple permutations of your proxy that differ solely by the list of `TranslationService` implementations they reference, but as you indicated, you'll need some custom Spring magic to achieve your second option unless you were to inject the required services (in your example "bing" and "google") along with the proxy into your business logic bean, and then pass those services in a `List` parameter to the proxy (instead of injecting them into the proxy at configuration-time.) In that sense, you'd still be using the "Strategy Pattern" but your Strategy container is now simply the List passed at runtime instead of referenced in your Proxy during configuration. There may be something more elegant here, but really it sounds like you'd be "moving dirt" so to speak. I'll think on it some more. This is a fun problem. =)